# Possibility of Nonzero or All Azimuthal $E$ Field Component of a Line Charge enclosed by a Gaussian Cylinder

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Source: https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-2/pages/6-3-applying-gausss-law

[image]

For a line charge on an axis, why is all of the E field only pointed in the $\hat{s}$ direction? How do we know that some of the component of the E field is not pointed in the $\hat{\phi}$ direction? When would there be a case where there is all or some in the $\hat{\phi}$ component of the E field when looking at line charges in cylindrical coordinates? Is it not possible because we purposely choose the cylindrical gaussian shape for line charges to only have one component of the E field be nonzero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the symmetry of the charge distribution must match the symmetry of the electric field. The charge distribution of an infinite, uniform line of charge is symmetrical under reflections across any axis that is perpendicular to it. For the symmetries to match, the electric field must always be perpendicular to the line of charge. For some visual aid, view the figures below:

[image]
[image]

Note: These figures are not my own and are from "Physics for Scientists and Engineeers: A Strategic Approach" by Randall Knight.